# why the function count_input not change the global a

Tags: python

I got a mission to right an age, if the age is 13,14,17,18,19 it need to become zero and than i need to sumerize all together and thats the answer.

```
def filter_teens(a_=13, b_=13, c_=13):
    d = fix_age(a_) + fix_age(b_) + fix_age(c_)
    return d

def fix_age(age):
    if 16 < age <=19:
        age = 0
    elif 13 <= age < 15:
        age = 0
    else:
        age = age
    return age

def count_input(numbers_of_letters):
    global a
    if numbers_of_letters == 0:
        a = 13
    else:
        a
               
a = input()
b = input()
c = input()

count_a = (a.count(a))
count_b = (b.count(b))
count_c = (c.count(c))

count_input(count_a)
```

thats the basic code why its not working?

Comment: You never print anything... So unclear what output you're expecting, or how you know anything is/isn't changing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never do anything related to ages, so unclear how that's related to the question.

`a.count(a)` will always equal 1. Therefore, nothing changes because you never reassign `a` inside of the else statement

---

The number of characters in that string can be obtained from `len(a)`.

To get number of *letters*, you need a regex to count `[a-zA-Z]`, for example.